# Converting an array list to a single string

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, compilation

I am working on a section of code for an assignment I am doing atm, and I am completely stuck with 1 little bit.

I need to convert the contents of an array list into a string, or the form of a string, which will be able to be  imput into toString() in order for it to be printed to the screen.

```
public String toString(){
    String full;
    full = (this.name + this.address + "\n" + "Student Number = " + this.studentId);
    for (int i = 0; i < cs.size(); i++) {
        full.append(cs[i]);
    return full;
```

The piece of above code is where i attempt to combine 3 varaibles and the contents of an array list into a single string with formatting.

Unfortunatly it creates an error "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList"

Thanks for any help.

Jake

Comment: You need to use StringBuilder rather than String to build a String.

Comment: I recommend to use a  `StringBuilder` instead of `+` for a `String`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cs is array list, so you have to do get operation, not [] (which is for array access)

It should be like:

```
full.append(cs.get(i));
```

Not

```
full.append(cs[i]);
```

EDIT: As assylis said, `full` should be `StringBuilder` not just `String`, because String doesn't support `append()` method.

`StringBuilder full = new StringBuilder()`;

Comment: @assylias: Yes, edited my answer. I was concentrating more on error than other parts.

Comment: It worked with only a slight bit of modification, thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to access an `ArrayList` as though it is a primitive array (using the square brackets around the index).  Try using the `get(int index)` method instead.

i.e.,

```
cs.get(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Commons StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) has different varieties of [join()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20char%29) methods that mean you don't have to write this yourself. You can specify the separator and even the prefix/suffix.

I would recommend you look at Apache Commons, not just for this but for lots of other useful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot index an `ArrayList` like an array, you need the `get(index)` method. Even better, use the enhanced `for` loop, since it's not recommended to index over a list, as the implementation may change to `LinkedList`.

I also suggest using a `StringBuilder` for efficiency:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder full = new StringBuilder();
    full.append(this.name);
    full.append(this.address);
    full.append("\n");
    full.append("Student Number = ");
    full.append(this.studentId);
    for (String s: cs)
        full.append(s);
    return full.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use 
"cs.get(i)" in place of "cs[i]".
as cs is an ArrayList not an Array.

and also use 
full = full + cs.get(i); and not full.append(cs.get(i));

as String type dont have a append method.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, since you don't put any spacers between each element of the `ArrayList` it might be unreadable. Consider using Guava's [Joiner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) class.

So instead of

```
 for (...)
   s.append(y);
```

if would be

```
   a.append(Joiner.on(" ").join(yourList));
```

The Joiner is also more efficient than the for loop since it uses a `StringBuilder` internally.